# Google KML import replace icons

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have map with custom icon https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/edit?mid=1iwhgwHJgtmYOS6PokVdvTqTgpB51xCAg&usp=sharing
After import in KML icon turn into this https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png

There is result KML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>test map</name>
    <description/>
    <Style id="icon-1594-7CB342-nodesc-normal">
      <IconStyle>
        <color>ff42b37c</color>
        <scale>1</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>0</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[<h3>$[name]</h3>]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="icon-1594-7CB342-nodesc-highlight">
      <IconStyle>
        <color>ff42b37c</color>
        <scale>1</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>1</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[<h3>$[name]</h3>]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="icon-1594-7CB342-nodesc">
      <Pair>
        <key>normal</key>
        <styleUrl>#icon-1594-7CB342-nodesc-normal</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
      <Pair>
        <key>highlight</key>
        <styleUrl>#icon-1594-7CB342-nodesc-highlight</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Folder>
      <name>Campings</name>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Ein Yarkam camping</name>
        <styleUrl>#icon-1594-7CB342-nodesc</styleUrl>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>
            35.039418,30.945092,0
          </coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KML Export from My Maps does not support all the icon options provided in MyMaps.  This is stated in the export dialog:

[image]

An alternative is to use the KMZ export (do not check the "Export as KML..." button), which will generate a KMZ file (zipped KML file) that includes the icon image bundled inside the zip.

Another option is to edit the KML in Google Earth or some other KML editor and change the icon.  If you wanted, you could extract the icon from the KMZ, host it online somewhere, and then put the URL for that icon into your KML file.